# package not found Error

Tags: java, vlcj

These packages show some errors when I import them.
What am I suppose to do?

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;       
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;

public class Tutorial1A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: All of them? Did you include the physical-libs (the files)?

Comment: What errors do they show you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the external library file `jna-version-number.jar` and `vlcj.jar` are added to your build path.
If not download `jna-3.0.9.jar` and `vlcj.jar`,paste it into your project folder,right click and add to build path.Assuming you are on eclipse. if not , you will have to add it however your IDE / Compiler requires